# Increase partition size in debian server

Tags: linux, debian, partition, parted

I have a debian server instance and I need to increase the root partition size of it. I installed the parted program and took a backup first. Then I attached another 2GB volume to the instance.

When I run "df" command it gives me this output.

```
Filesystem                                             1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs                                                   2063184 1726312    232068  89% /
udev                                                       10240       0     10240   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                     102288      88    102200   1% /run
/dev/disk/by-uuid/3068f754-1f20-4436-8445-c287cc497619   2063184 1726312    232068  89% /
tmpfs                                                       5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                     204560       0    204560   0% /run/shm
```

In parted console when I run "print devices" command I got this.

```
(parted) print devices                                                    
/dev/xvdb (2147MB)
/dev/xvda (2147MB)
```

When I run "print free" command I got this.

```
(parted)print free                                                       
Model: Xen Virtual Block Device (xvd)
Disk /dev/xvdb: 2147MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
        32.3kB  1049kB  1016kB           Free Space
 1      1049kB  2147MB  2146MB  primary  ext4         boot
```

When I run "print all" in parted I got this.

```
(parted) print all                                                        
Model: Xen Virtual Block Device (xvd)
Disk /dev/xvdb: 2147MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  2147MB  2146MB  primary  ext4         boot
```

So there are two devices. One is a free volume.I need to merge these two and make one root volume which has 4GB on it. So any one please tell me what is the command should I use in parted?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to span the root volume across multiple disks, but it would be less dangerous and more maintainable in the long run to mount one of /usr, /home, or /var to the new disk.

- temporarily mount the new disk
- copy from the current /xxx directory to the new disk
- rename the original directory temporarily to /xxx-old
- update fstab to point /xxx at the new volume
- reboot
- if everything looks good, delete /xxx-old

The benefit to this approach is that it both frees up room on / and allows easier backups. You can put the data that is more important on the new volume and back that 2GB up when it changes rather having to back up all 4GB every time.